# How to kill window from a different tmux session?

Tags: tmux

Is there a way to find and kill a tmux window from a different tmux session? Or do I need to attach to the other session and then find the window to kill? How do I do this with cmd line?

```
tmux kill-window ...?
```

Comment: Note, if you name your window it will be easier to kill it with `kill-window -t sessionname:windowname`

Answer (score 0):

Use `-t` to `kill-window`, look at https://man.openbsd.org/tmux#COMMANDS and https://man.openbsd.org/tmux#kill-window.

You can use `list-sessions`, `list-windows` or `list-panes` to find the pane or window you want.

You could also do it interactively using tree mode, `C-b s` or `C-b w` then find the window then `x` (or `:kill-window` - no `C-b` - if your tmux is too old to have `x` in tree mode).